# Return true/false for collection of mapped true or false values

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array (called `acceptedGrades`) of accepted "grades". My `json` returns a grade for each person. This grade must be in the `acceptedGrades` array TO return true, if not it returns false. Example:

```
acceptedGrades = ['A1','A2','A3','B1','B2','B3','C1','C2','C3'];

for "A1" returns true;
for "Z1" returns false;
```

The next code looks for this to decide if its true or false.

```
data.map((item) => {
    this.state.isValidGrade = acceptedGrades.includes(item.grade.toUpperCase());
});
```

Now, the problem is I want to know if ALL items returns true or someone returns false, e.g.

```
0:grade: 'B1' //true
1:grade: 'C2' //true
2:grade: 'A3' //true
// All return TRUE so expected result should be TRUE

0:grade: 'B11' //false
1:grade: 'C2' //true
2:grade: 'A3' //true
// Not All return TRUE so the expected result should be FALSE
```

I might be going around this the wrong way, and believe there is a simpler way to look at all values of grade as a collect against the `acceptedGrades` array rather than look at each individual person - any suggestions or answer?

Comment: `data.every(item => acceptedGrades.includes(item.grade)) // true or false`

Comment: I think you already have it. `.includes` will return false if it doesn't exist. Are you saying you want `this.state.isValueGrade` to include something other than a `boolean` value? Like an `object` (`{ isValidGrade: boolean, grade: string}`)?

Comment: Nearly had it.. needed to add data.every as above inside my mapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the logic inside a method, and actually check if you can found a `grade` that is not included in the set of valid grades, if you find some item verifying this condition you will know the entire array of items will not be valid:

```js
const acceptedGrades = ['A1','A2','A3','B1','B2','B3','C1','C2','C3'];

// Data examples.

const data1 = [
    {name: "Josh", grade: "B1"},
    {name: "Lucas", grade: "C2"},
    {name: "Damian", grade: "A3"}
];

const data2 = [
    {name: "Josh", grade: "B11"},
    {name: "Lucas", grade: "C2"},
    {name: "Damian", grade: "A3"}
];

// Method that return if a set of grades is valid or not.

const isValidGrade = (data) =>
{
    return !data.find(({grade}) => !acceptedGrades.includes(grade.toUpperCase()));
};

console.log(isValidGrade(data1));
console.log(isValidGrade(data2));
```

However, it would be more clear if you use `every()`:

```
const isValidGrade = (data) =>
{
    return data.every(({grade}) => acceptedGrades.includes(grade.toUpperCase()));
};
```